# How do i solve "PREVIEW UPDATE ERROR" issue in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I setup an Xcode SwiftUI project, and try to run the simulator for the first time, but i keep getting this error. It is weird because i have not edited anything. below is the error that shows up:

```
== PREVIEW UPDATE ERROR:

    RemoteHumanReadableError: Unknown preview provider "ContentView_Previews"
    
    2048 does not contain a preview provider named "ContentView_Previews". Check your build settings to ensure the preview provider is compiled into your product.
```

here is the actual code:

```
import SwiftUI
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
    #if DEBUG
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    #endif
```

I am running the simulator and it fails, can anyone explain why this keeps happening? i tried it on different macs and the same issue occurs.

note: im running on xcode Version 14.3.1

Comment: What happens if you remove the `#if DEBUG` compiler directives?

Comment: You are probably in release mode check your schema

Comment: removing #if DEBUG does not solve it. I also changed Release to Debug for command-line builds but the error remains.